# Displaying admin notices inside the block editor from rest_after_insert_{$this->post_type} hook

Tags: php, javascript, block-editor

After saving my custom posttype 'openpub-press-item' I use the action '[rest_after_insert_openpub-press-item](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_after_insert_this-post_type/)'. Within this hook I want to create an admin notice and display the notice in the block editor. I've spend hours searching for a solution online but I can't figure it out.

In the classic editor I could simply use the action '[admin_notices](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/)' but unfortunately this action does not work inside the block editor.

This code should do the trick:

```
(function (wp) {
    wp.data.dispatch("core/notices").createNotice(
        "success", // Can be one of: success, info, warning, error.
        "Post published!", // Text string to display.
        {
            isDismissible: true, // Whether the user can dismiss the notice.
            // Any actions the user can perform.
            actions: [
                {
                    url: "#",
                    label: "View post",
                },
            ],
        }
    );
})(window.wp);
```

But I'm clueless on how to implement this code into the hook that I'm using. Any help is appreciated.